# Removing "textview" voiceover in Ionic App with TalkBack

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor, ionic5, capacitor-plugin

I am working on my app and want to remove the 'textview' feature for VoiceOver when TalkBack is enabled on Android.

However, it doesn't seem to be working as expected. Has anyone encountered this problem before or found a solution?

We are using Ionic 6.20.1 and Capacitor 4.7.0 with Vue 3.3.7.

I have tried using the aria-hidden="true" attribute (in main paths), but it is not working. It seems that the problem persists despite trying this solution. Does anyone have any other ideas or suggestions to address this problem? I appreciate any help you can provide.